# Root scope for service worker in src/

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I need to register a service worker on the root scope:`/`.  I host the website currently locally with `ng serve`. The website is build using `angular6`. The directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── angular.json
├── service-worker.js
└── src
    ├── app
    ├── assets
    └── index.html
```

I would want to move the `service-worker.js` file to the `src/` directory as well. But if I do the service worker can only be registered on the scope `/src/`.

How can I move the `service-worker.js` to the `src` directory?

Answer (score -1):

To move the service worker to src and still keep scope as '/' you will have to write this header to the service worker file.

```
Service-Worker-Allowed: /
```